# how to give the positions for the drag and drop nodes using cypress

Tags: cypress

```
   const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
    cy.get('.eccgui-grid__column > .bp3-input-group > .bp3-input').type('Source path').get('[data-test-id="ruleEditor-sidebar-draggable-operator-sourcePathInput"]').trigger("dragstart", { dataTransfer, clientX: 200, clientY: 300 });
    cy.get('#ruleEditor-react-flow-canvas').trigger("drop", { dataTransfer })
    cy.get('#ruleEditor-react-flow-canvas').trigger("dragend", { dataTransfer }).click();
```

Above is my code I am new to cypress how to give the positions for the drag and drop in canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Install cypress plugin @4tw/cypress-drag-drop
Load the plugin in your code by add the below line in your command.js file

`require('@4tw/cypress-drag-drop')`

Or, if you are using ES module syntax:

`import '@4tw/cypress-drag-drop'`

Finally, the use the below code for drag and drop

`cy.get('.sourceitem').drag('.target', {source: { x: 100, y: 100 }, target: { position: 'left' }, force: true })`